# Ionic2 Angular2 - Is there any way to resolve promises before changing page in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I store certain information in SqlStorage. When I attempt to retrive that information I get a promise:

```
export class ProfileService {
  this.storage = new Storage(sqlStorage);

  get fname() {
    this.storage.get('fname');
  }
  ...
  ..

}
```

Now when displaying user's profile, I need to display information from profile service:

```
@Page({
  ...
})
export class DisplayProfile {
  fname: AbstractControl;

  constructor(private _profile: ProfileService) {

     // SEE HERE
     this._profile.get('fname').then(value => {
       this.fname.value = value;
    });

    this._profile.get('lname').then(value=>{
     ...
   });
  }

}
```

As you can see above, I am resolving promises in the contructor of the Page.
I rather have these promises resolved before page load (just like resolve blocks in Angular1 state change).

Any clue how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of page load life cycle events that occur for pages in an Ionic app.  You might look at and see if `@ionViewWillEnter` or `@ionViewCanEnter` will work for you.

The full list of those life cycles and explanations to how they can be used can be found here: [Ionic Lifecycle](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/)